# manipulate slides in Latex Beamer

Tags: beamer

I created a beamer slide, What I want to do in the next slide is:

1. Blur the previous slide and have it as background of the new slide
2. Creating a box and write a few lines in it.

note that the in the first slides I have columns containing pictures and TikZ picture.

Is there an elegant way to this except of a copy and paste solution?

Comment: Does this procedure has to be repeated or do you need it just for one slide?

Comment: For only one slide.

Comment: In that case you might want to save as image the previous slide and use it as `background` for the next one.

Comment: Is there any command to do so? I mean saving first slide as an image?

Comment: Comment out the other slides or duplicate the file and remove all but the desired slide. Compile the file to create a PDF of the slide. You can now include it as a background for other slides. You should rename it so you don't overwrite it when you compile again.

Comment: thanks for the solution, but as you may read in the Question "Is there an elegant way to this except of a copy and paste solution?"

Comment: It won't be worth it for a single slide. If you wanted to do this for many slides, it would be worth your spending the time and energy to do it elegantly. But for a single slide, it just isn't worth it. How long are you prepared to spend developing an elegant solution *vs* an inelegant one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to do it without copying the code for the current slide is to use overlays coupled with TikZ. You could use one overlay to create a semitransparent rectangle to cover the current slide, and at the same time add the box for the additional text (the coordinates for the rectangle may need some tweaking depending on your particular layout).

Example:

[image: blurred background example]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{A sample slide}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % we don't want to affect the bounding box if the rectangle is too large
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            % the following coords. may need to be changed to suit your slides
            \fill <2> [fill=white, opacity=0.8] (0,0) rectangle (12, 7);
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \node <2> [draw, shape=rectangle, align=left] at (4, 4) {%
            Very interesting sample text about\\
            an even more interesting sample subject
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have used this method to prepare slides, and it should work regardless of the background you're using.